# I'm unable to boot to Ubuntu after Chrome OS Dual Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, google-chrome, chromium, chromebook

Recently I've seen this tutorial : [Install Chrome OS on Laptop](https://www.watchmetech.com/dual-boot-cloudready-chrome-os-windows-10-pc/)

I've tried installing Chrome OS on my Laptop. That tutorial has a Dual Boot Function. So I've dual Booted it with Windows 10 and it working fine for me

Later I've formatted my Laptop and Installed Ubuntu 16.04 and tried to Dual Boot or Install with Chrome OS using that Tutorial, But from then I'm unable to boot to Ubuntu . Please Help ?

Thank you.

Comment: What bootloader are you using?

Comment: Show you boot-loader picture, May be it is chrome-os boot loader have completely replaced.